# Call Function Based On Parameter Name

Tags: php

I am passing a parameter, "action", to another file, process.php. The value of "action" will be the name of a function that is defined within process.php.  If the function exists, it should be called automatically.   I tried the following:

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
$function = {$action}();

if(function_exists($function))
    $function;
else
    die('No function.');
```

That, however, does not work.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: You really just shouldn't do that, unless you want to get hacked.

Answer (score 3):

As @Positive said you are calling the function on assignment. I just wanted to add a few things - this is a bit risky - what if the request contents were 'phpinfo' or something even more dangerous. Perhaps a better idea would be to select the function from an array of allowed functions:

```
$allowed_functions = array(
    'my_function_one',
    'my_function_two'
);
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if(in_array($action,$allowed_functions)){
    {$action}();
}
else {
    die('No function.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the assignment to `$function` like below. Note that function_exists only take the function name.

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
$function = $action;
```

Actually you are calling the function with this statment `$result = $function();`, see [Variable functions<sup>*PHP-Manual*</sup>](http://php.net/functions.variable-functions).

and also sanitize the GET parameter according to your function name conventions.